# css float issue (nav and article)

Tags: html, css, css-float, nav

I have a nav bar and an article in my html page. I want the nav bar to be floating on the left side of the page and the article on the right side: but I don't want the article to wrap around the nav.

```
<nav>
            <ul> 
                <li id="startButton" class="ui-selected"><div>Inicio</div></li>
                <li id="servicesButton"><div>Servicios</div></li>
                <li id="offersButton"><div>Ofertas</div></li>
                <li id="contactButton"><div>Contacto</div></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <article id="start">
            <p>Y, viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con muestras de tanta tristeza, le dijo: Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro. Todas estas borrascas que nos suceden son señales de que presto ha de serenar el tiempo y han de sucedernos bien las cosas; porque no es posible que el mal ni el bien sean durables, y de aquí se sigue que, habiendo durado mucho el mal, el bien está ya cerca.</p>
            <p>Así que, no debes congojarte por las desgracias que a mí me suceden, pues a ti no te cabe parte dellas. Y, viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con muestras de tanta tristeza, le dijo: Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro.</p>

            <p>Todas estas borrascas que nos suceden son señales de que presto ha de serenar el tiempo y han de sucedernos bien las cosas; porque no es posible que el mal ni el bien sean durables, y de aquí se sigue que, habiendo durado mucho el mal, el bien está ya cerca. Así que, no debes congojarte por las desgracias que a mí me suceden, pues a ti no te cabe parte dellas. Y, viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con muestras de tanta tristeza, le dijo: Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro.</p>

            <p>Todas estas borrascas que nos suceden son señales de que presto ha de serenar el tiempo y han de sucedernos bien las cosas; porque no es posible que el mal ni el bien sean durables, y de aquí se sigue que, habiendo durado mucho el mal, el bien está ya cerca. Así que, no debes congojarte por las desgracias que a mí me suceden, pues a ti no te cabe parte dellas. Y, viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con muestras de tanta tristeza, le dijo: Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro. Todas estas borrascas que nos suceden son señales de que presto ha de serenar el tiempo y han de sucedernos bien las cosas; porque no es posible que el mal ni el bien sean durables, y de aquí se sigue que, habiendo durado mucho el mal, el bien está ya cerca. Así que, no debes congojarte por las desgracias que a mí me suceden,</p>
        </article>
```

My code is in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qu6jqcrk/

I have tried floating the article but it gets pushed down the nav bar. Can anyone help me figuring it out?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some solutions. One is to use `display: table-cell` to `article`:

```css
nav {
  float: left;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  left: -20px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul li {
  border: 2px solid #051838;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 16px;
  font-family: Lucida Console;
  cursor: pointer;
}
article {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: table-cell;
}
article p {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li id="startButton" class="ui-selected">
      <div>Inicio</div>
    </li>
    <li id="servicesButton">
      <div>Servicios</div>
    </li>
    <li id="offersButton">
      <div>Ofertas</div>
    </li>
    <li id="contactButton">
      <div>Contacto</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<article id="start">
  <p>Y, viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con muestras de tanta tristeza, le dijo: Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro. Todas estas borrascas que nos suceden son señales de que presto ha de serenar el tiempo y han
    de sucedernos bien las cosas; porque no es posible que el mal ni el bien sean durables, y de aquí se sigue que, habiendo durado mucho el mal, el bien está ya cerca.</p>
  <p>Así que, no debes congojarte por las desgracias que a mí me suceden, pues a ti no te cabe parte dellas. Y, viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con muestras de tanta tristeza, le dijo: Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más
    que otro.</p>
  <p>Todas estas borrascas que nos suceden son señales de que presto ha de serenar el tiempo y han de sucedernos bien las cosas; porque no es posible que el mal ni el bien sean durables, y de aquí se sigue que, habiendo durado mucho el mal, el bien está
    ya cerca. Así que, no debes congojarte por las desgracias que a mí me suceden, pues a ti no te cabe parte dellas. Y, viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con muestras de tanta tristeza, le dijo: Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro
    si no hace más que otro.</p>
  <p>Todas estas borrascas que nos suceden son señales de que presto ha de serenar el tiempo y han de sucedernos bien las cosas; porque no es posible que el mal ni el bien sean durables, y de aquí se sigue que, habiendo durado mucho el mal, el bien está
    ya cerca. Así que, no debes congojarte por las desgracias que a mí me suceden, pues a ti no te cabe parte dellas. Y, viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con muestras de tanta tristeza, le dijo: Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro
    si no hace más que otro. Todas estas borrascas que nos suceden son señales de que presto ha de serenar el tiempo y han de sucedernos bien las cosas; porque no es posible que el mal ni el bien sean durables, y de aquí se sigue que, habiendo durado
    mucho el mal, el bien está ya cerca. Así que, no debes congojarte por las desgracias que a mí me suceden,</p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2):

use `white-space:nowrap;`

```
article {
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: block;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

try this
http://jsfiddle.net/qu6jqcrk/5/

Answer (score 2):

Just give the article a width, float it to the right, and also use nowrap

```
article {
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 60%; /* You need to define a width */
    float: right
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

[See working example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/qu6jqcrk/8/)

**Note:** Width is very important so that the article width doesn't grow excessively.

Answer (score 2):

you can wrap with a div:

```
<div class="Left">
    <nav>
        ...
    </nav>
</div>      
<div class="Right">
    <article id="start">
        ...
    </article>
</div>

.Right {
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
}

.Left {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shiralizadeh/qu6jqcrk/6/)

Answer (score 2):

Use display: table-cell for article

```
article {
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alemarch/qu6jqcrk/10/